# Image intent closes upon launch

Tags: android, android-intent, download, xamarin

I download an image, copy it to a public folder and try to open it with an image intent.

But when I start the intent, my app goes tries to open another window, which immediately closes and it goes back to the app.

Why is that happening?

```
public Intent CopyToPublic(string privatePath)
{
    string extBasePath = global::Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.Path;
    string upperFolder = "MyApp";
    var bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes (privatePath);

    Java.IO.File f = new Java.IO.File (extBasePath + "/" + upperFolder);
    if (!f.Exists()) f.Mkdir ();

    var extPath = String.Format ("{0}/{1}/{2}", extBasePath, upperFolder, "cache.jpg");
    System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes (extPath, bytes);

    global::Android.Net.Uri uri = global::Android.Net.Uri.Parse (extPath);

    Intent intent = new Intent (Intent.ActionView);
    intent.SetDataAndType (uri, "image/*");

    return intent;
}

//Open
StartActivity (FilePublisher.Static.CopyToPublic(path));
```

the `extPath` in this case is `/storage/emulated/0/Miraclix/cache.jpg`, which exists when I check it with a file explorer.

Comment: @Stan, yes. It is Xamarin.

Comment: cache.jpg exists. Ok. 0 bytes? Visible with an image viewer from explorer? File size like on server?

Comment: @greenapps `cache.jpg` has 48 Kb. But the funny thing is, when I choose the FileExplorer fo open the intent, the image not not able to be loaded.

Comment: Thats not funny at all. Compare cache.jpg with the one on the server. Hmmm... i do not quite understand what you are doing. You should browse with a file explorer to the .jpg and then let the file explorer open a viewer for the image.

Comment: I can open the copied image from the file explorer app. I can not open the image from an intent.

Comment: Try an intent on an existing file so you do not have to copy first.

Comment: @greenapps Can you verify that the upper code is correct for copying the image file?

Comment: No. I have no Xamarin. But why should i? You already told that the image was ok. So why this doubt? As your problem has nothing to do with downloading you should now only concentrate on how to use a view intent.